# Returning a comma separated string from a function breaking the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am calling this function:

val(array[i][index])

when i try to pass a time stamp **123,213,121,212**

where:

```
   function val(m) {

        try {
            if (m == null) return '';
            if (typeof m == 'number') return num(m);
            if (typeof m == 'string') return str(m);
            if (typeof m == 'boolean') return m ? 'true' : 'false';
            return m.length ? arr(m) : obj(m);

        }
        catch (err) {

            return "";

        }


    }
    function num(m) { return m; }
    function str(m) {

        return m.substr(0, 6) == '/Date(' ? dfmt(date(m)) : m;
    }
    function date(s) { return new Date(parseFloat(/Date\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(s)[1])); }
    function pad(d) { return d < 10 ? '0' + d : d; }
    function dfmt(d) { return d.getFullYear() + '/' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + pad(d.getDate()); }
```

The function failed.

It might be due to a comma.

How can i solve this.

Any help is appreciated

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

Actually the value "123.135.414.414" is of Object type

SO i need to write something like:

```
  function val(m) {

        try {
            if (m == null) return '';
            if (typeof m == 'object') return m;
            if (typeof m == 'number') return num(m);
            if (typeof m == 'string') return str(m);
            if (typeof m == 'boolean') return m ? 'true' : 'false';
            return m.length ? arr(m) : obj(m);

        }
        catch (err) {

            return "Time Stamp";

        }


    }
```

This solves my problem for this time.

Any further suggestion is welcomed

Comment: @cederlof I am calling this function when i get the json data from a service and then parsing it. So IE does not point to any location instead it shows the JSON data failed to load. It enters the val function but not able to reply back

Comment: It seems that the date(s) function is the culprit, but that's just a quick guess by a quick glance.

Comment: @omarello My problem get solved

Comment: Please post your solution and accept it, so that people having the same problem as yours will be able to find their answer on this site. @KamalDeepSingh.

Comment: @Truth I have posted my answer but cant accept in 2 days

Comment: In which case, wait 2 days and accept it :). Simple enough :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Actually the value "123.135.414.414" is of Object type

SO i need to write something like:

function val(m) {

```
    try {
        if (m == null) return '';
        if (typeof m == 'object') return m;
        if (typeof m == 'number') return num(m);
        if (typeof m == 'string') return str(m);
        if (typeof m == 'boolean') return m ? 'true' : 'false';
        return m.length ? arr(m) : obj(m);

    }
    catch (err) {

        return "Time Stamp";

    }


}
```